# XML para DB com PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Criei um código que lê o XML e depois insere no banco de dados MYSQL, porém apenas tenta, pois um erro é retornado. Está simplório pois estou fazendo por blocos.

Arquivo `conn.php`

```
<?php
if(!session_id())
{
    session_start();
}
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'eliseu', '123mudar', 'xml');
mysqli_query($mysqli, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Arquivo `index.php` [Lê XML e grava no DB Mysql]

```
<?php
include_once("conn.php");
$arquivo_xml = simplexml_load_file('options.xml');
$cores = $arquivo_xml->cor[0]->value;
$count_cor = count($arquivo_xml->cor[0]->value);
####### FILTRA VAR
if( !function_exists('filtra_var') )
{
    function filtra_var($var) {
        $var = trim($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        $var = htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        //$var = fgetss($var);
        $var = addslashes($var);
        $var = filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        return $var;
    }
}
####### PREPARAR MYSQL INSERT
if( !function_exists('insert_data') ){
    function insert_data($valor,$cat,$desc=NULL)
    {
        $valor = filtra_var($valor);
        ##
        $cat = filtra_var($valor);
        ##
        $desc = filtra_var($desc);
        ##
        $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `site_options` (`opt_value`,`opt_option`.`opt_desc`) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $valor) . "','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $cat) . "','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $desc) . "') LIMIT 1;");
        $exec_sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        unset($exec_sql);
    }
}
#######
for($x=0;$x<$count_cor;$x++)
{
    if(insert_data($cores[$x],'Cor',''))
    {
        echo "<strong>Inserido:<strong> " . $cores[$x] . "<br>";
    }
}
echo "<hr>";
$combustivel = $arquivo_xml->combustivel[0]->value;
$count_combustivel = count($arquivo_xml->combustivel[0]->value);
for($x=0;$x<$count_combustivel;$x++)
{
    if(insert_data($cores[$x],'Combustível',''))
    {
        echo "<strong>Inserido:<strong> " . $combustivel[$x] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

A estrutura do arquivo `options.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<options>
    <cor>
        <value>Amarelo</value>
        <value>Azul</value>
        <value>Verde</value>
        <value>Branco</value>
        <value>Prata</value>
        <value>Outros</value>
    </cor>
    <combustivel>
        <value>Gasolina</value>
        <value>Álcool</value>
        <value>Flex</value>
    </combustivel>
</options>
```

Retorna o erro na tela:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   null given in X:\Apache2\www\xml\index.php on line 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

corrigi definindo variável global para o link da conexão `$mysqli`:

```
####### PREPARAR MYSQL INSERT
if( !function_exists('insert_data') ){
    function insert_data($valor,$cat,$desc=NULL)
    {
        global $mysqli // Inseri o link de conexão como global
        ## 
        $valor = filtra_var($valor);
        ##
        $cat = filtra_var($valor);
        ##
        $desc = filtra_var($desc);
        ##
        $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `site_options` (`opt_value`,`opt_option`,`opt_desc`) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $valor) . "','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $cat) . "','" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $desc) . "') LIMIT 1;");
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    }
}
```